# Cohabit versus Cohabitate?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

What is the difference between **cohabit** and **cohabitate**? I know the general definition of these words, but I cannot distinguish between the two (i.e., in my mind the definitions are identical).

I see that `cohabit` is in (Google's) online dictionary and cohabitate is not, but in practice the two seem to be used interchangeably.

Comment: Although this might sound like "the difference between converse and conversate", both can be found [in the dictionary.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohabitate)

Comment: OMG thanks, I didn't think to look in the dictionary before posting this question!

Comment: @Cascabel - Actually the available online definitions of the two are confusing at best -- they are typically cross-referenced, with few clues to the subtleties between.

Comment: @HotLicks I concur...that is why I did not vote to close. But the Q should show some effort and an explanation of why the definitions did not help.

Comment: Both may be in Merriam-Webster Online, but only _cohabit_ is in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003). Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two terms are synonyms. They both derive from Latin “cohabitare”. Cohabitate is a later formation.

***cohabit (v.):***

> "to dwell together," specifically "to dwell together as husband and wife," 1530s, a back-formation from cohabitation (q.v.) or else from Late Latin cohabitare. *A euphemism to describe a couple living together without benefit of marriage and usually implying sexual intercourse.*

***cohabitate (v.):***

> 1630s, from Late Latin cohabitatus, past participle of cohabitare "to dwell together," from co- "with, together" (see co-) + habitare "to live, inhabit, dwell”.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Any specific reason for the down-vote ? @Hotlicks comment clearly indicates no fault in the question. I've up-voted to even things out. +1.

Comment: No idea - wasn't met! @user067531 thanks for the post (upvoted). I'm in denial that they are indeed synonyms, but I will accept the answer (psychologically and in practice) if I don't hear from others soon!